# Why my layout doesn't work properly in welcome.blade

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-livewire

i'm working on a laravel project and i prepared a layout for welcome.blade but css and html don't work properly . somehow the project can't read them .

i make you sure that my paths is correct
even i change folders and paths in public but it didn't work

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="MealOrder">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript">
    <meta name="author" content="HiBootstrap">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Fafo - قالب رستوران و فست فود</title>
    <link rel="icon" src="/assets/images/tab.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">

    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/assets/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/assets/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/assets/css/animate.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/assets/css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

   
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/assets/css/responsive.css" type="text/css" media="all" />


    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  <script src="/assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  @livewireScripts   
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Probably you forgot run: npm run dev in your terminal.

Comment: why npm ??  i didn't use webpack/laravel-mix   @MartinAmu

Comment: Doesn't matter as @Adnane Kadri said you should compile your assets.

Comment: Check your console, it will likely tell you that these files can't be found. Then the question is, where did you put them in you Laravel project?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use Laravel 9 because Laravel now is using `vite` instead of `webpack/laravel-mix` as we used to see, and the way `vite` injects styles & scripts in layouts pages are not the same as it was.

you will need to add the following blade directive into your layout file:

```php
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```

and then re-run `npm run build` or `npm run dev` to re-bundle your assets.

more about [Bundling Assets (Vite)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite)

Comment: no i use laravel 8  and i don't use webpack/laravel-mix  .. i hadn't this bug in my previous projects

Answer (score 0):

its better change all src to asset() for example:
instead of

write

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="{{asset('assets/css/animate.min.css')}}" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

and for scripts do same

Comment: ok but src  worked  in my all previous project ... is it related to laravel version ? or it's a random bug

Comment: right click page and inspect then click on css link(bootstrap.rtl.min.css).that open css file correctly?